# Angularjs form validation not working

Tags: angularjs

A simple angularjs form validation is not working in any of the browsers. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE. I am not sure what is the problem. Is there any thing wrong in the code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Number only</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller("numOnlyRegex", function ($scope)
            {
                $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d+$/;
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="numOnlyRegex">
            <form name="myForm">
                Pin:<input type="text" ng-model="pin" ng-pattern="numOnlyRegex" name="pin" /><br/>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey i checked it working perfectly :)
Here is plunker "http://plnkr.co/edit/Fni3pDdOvYA8B7IpRCzD?p=preview"

Comment: But I am able to type letters in the input field in the plunker

Comment: Or atleast before submitting I want to check if the user typed in is only numbers or throw error message. Also the error message in the span tag keeps displaying even after entering correct value

Comment: This will validate in the way that it will set the form validity to invalid whne you type in letters in the input field but it won't stop you from typing in letters. If you want to do that then you'd need to intercept a keyup event for example where you can check for every character if it is a number

Comment: @NexusDuck That's ok if the user types in letters. I want to show error when the user tries to submit the form saying that "letters are not allowed"

Comment: @NexusDuck And when you say form validity to invalid - user will not be able to submit the form?

Comment: @kittu No, but you can prevent him from doing so, for example by calling a method through ng-submit and checking for the forms validity there

Comment: @NexusDuck Ok if I am not wrong, I have write a controller where in a method should check whether input text contains only numbers right?

Comment: @Kittu I tried to solve your problem with custom directive please check :)

Comment: @kittu Not exactly, you check if the input control is valid with your ng-pattern, in your controller you do have to write a method, but one that will check if the form is valid, a form can be accessed by giving it a name attribute in html and via that name you can check `formName.$valid` which will be false if any of it's input fields are invalid . For more info on this check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: @kittu use <span ng-show="myForm.pin.$invalid">Error</span> for error message below input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to disable the submit button on invalid input!

```
 <input type="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"  value="Submit" />
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/taYmWHzGHf6uVEfYKn5Q?p=preview)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks NLN and also Along with disabling the button,how can I show a error message below input text box if the user enters letters?

Comment: @kittu add  a span containing an error message that you will conditionally show (with ng-show for example) when the input control is $invalid

Comment: @kittu: You just need to add a span for that and use ng-show directive to display error message.

Comment: @kittu: Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/taYmWHzGHf6uVEfYKn5Q?p=preview)

Comment: The form is not getting disabled for the digit only input(i.e. pincode/zipcode). Please check the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nMyfgV9kfyza1ErcpF7N?p=preview

Comment: You forgot to add `ng-model="pin"` for the last `<input>`. Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/unc2FzXbnsJ2pHKULa1R?p=preview)